# BulkInsertOrUpdate with child entity use of efcore.bulkextensions

Tags: c#, .net-core, efcore.bulkextensions

I am using BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync  method to upsert the 20000 records in net-core 3.0. There is no error at all when doing this. it is upserting all the record with parent and child entity into database.

```
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig()
            {
                SetOutputIdentity = true,
                PreserveInsertOrder = true
            };   
var subEntities = new List<ItemHistory>(); 
await _dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities, bulkConfig);
    
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
   foreach (var subEntity in entity.ItemHistories)
    {
     subEntity.ItemId = entity.ID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
    }
    subEntities.AddRange(entity.ItemHistories);
}
await _airportDBContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(subEntities})
```

But when I am checking the records into database, many of the records having the child entity is referring wrong 'ItemId'. Even when I am executing this again with existing record, it is inserting some of the records again into child entity. while for the parent entity is working fine in both of the scenario. Is there any issue in my code? Or is it a known issue with this package?

I am referring this https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions#read-example

and it might be same as this issue:- https://www.bountysource.com/issues/76836788-bulkinsertorupdateasync-ids-not-setting-correctly

Could you anyone having idea to overcome this problem.

Comment: if your parent and child tables have relationships, you don't need to set ItemId. EFCore will set ItemId automatically for you.

Comment: @Asherguru No, if you check the documentation of efcore.bulkextension then they are using the same thing

Comment: There's no such thing as a bulk update much less bulk upsert. Only bulk inserts, performed by bcp, BULK INSERT or SqlBulkCopy. Those operations all insert a large amount of data using minimal logging - instead of logging individual row operations, the entire data pages inserted are logged. When rolling back, the entire pages are rolled back. What you describe is batch, not bulk operations, and it SHOULDN't be done using an ORM

Comment: ORMs like EF are meant to Map Objects to Relational tables. You don't have objects in this case, you have an ETL job working with rows. The *batch* operations you tried to perform will store all data in a staging table, eg a temporary table, and perform an UPDATE and INSERT against the target table

Comment: Why are you using EF Core at all? Why not insert the data directly to the target table, or a staging table? It will be a **LOT** faster and easier than what you're doing right now - loading every single record in memory before sending it to the server, only for it to be stored in a temporary table. Where do the ItemHistory data rows (they aren't entities) come from?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you check the above link for bulkextension they given BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync in their  documentation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Have you ever worked with efcore.bulkextension ? This is all about requirement.

Comment: I know what those are. They are batch operations, not bulk operations. And ORMs aren't meant for ETL jobs. If you have 200K rows that come from a CSV the easiest and fastest way would be to open the file with CsvDataReader and write it to a stagint table using SqlBulkCopy, then perform an UPDATE/INSERT with just two SQL commands. That's probably 200K times faster than trying to use the ORM

Comment: @BuntyChoudhary I'm importing a lot more than just 200K rows every 15 minutes, with far more complex formats than a simple CSV file. I use CsvHelper, FastMember's ObjectReader, SqlBulkCopy everywhere, pipelines using TPL Dataflow. If I used an ORM for this it would take hours

Comment: You should really check [Is an ORM the right tool for migrating data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137840/is-a-orm-the-right-tool-to-use-for-migrating-data). The answer is no. It doesn't matter if this is a requirement or not, the tool is simply wrong. It's like trying to use an electric scooter to transfer a truckload of rocks

Comment: Even if you insist on using this, you *have* to understand what's going on underneath to avoid problems like the one you have now. There's no bulk update. Neither SQL, the language, nor SQL Server (or any other database) have bulk updates. The fast way is what I described - insert the data into staging tables, then perform an `UPDATE target ... INNER JOIN` between the staging table and the target to update existing rows followed by `INSERT ... LEFT JOIN` to find new rows. You could use a `MERGE` statement to do both at the same time *but* MERGE isn't atomic so it needs an explicit transaction

Comment: The staging table may be either a temporary table created by the tool, or a table variable which is backed by tempdb, just like a temporary storage. The other option is to pass multiple rows in batches of ~1000 rows through a value constructor. The problem here is this would result in 200 separate calls in your case. EF Core already uses this trick to batch data

Comment: Those are the options. Even with nested entities, those batch extensions can only work this way. Related entities would be stored in different staging tables, but the extension still has to use staging tables. With db-generated keys though, there's a problem - the related entities can't be loaded without knowing the root IDs. The ORM either has to insert the data one table at a time, or try to use heuristics to guess the relations *after* inserting the data. Something that can easily fail

Comment: That's no different than how ADO.NET's DataSet and related tables worked by the way. This isn't a library limitation, it's how RDBMSs work. To avoid this problem *don't* establish relations on the client using auto-generated keys. If the data have a key already, use it. Otherwise, the typical way is to look up related entities using surrogate keys or any other uniquely identifying characteristic to retrieve their ID in the INSERT/UPDATE operation. That's what the Lookup transform in SSIS does by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer for this

```
var bulkConfig = new BulkConfig()
            {
                SetOutputIdentity = true,
                PreserveInsertOrder = true
            };   
var subEntities = new List<ItemHistory>(); 
entities = entities.ForEach(i => i.ID == 0);
await _dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities, bulkConfig);

    
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
   foreach (var subEntity in entity.ItemHistories)
    {
     subEntity.ItemId = entity.ID; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
    }
    subEntities.AddRange(entity.ItemHistories);
}
await _airportDBContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(subEntities});
```